# Simple Soccer Algorithm with positive ROI

Tags: patentability, prior-art, sell, sellpatent

I developed a simple algorithm that works at providing an effective positive roi in the long run in the field of soccer betting, not differing much from the one computed theoretically. I am now expanding it to the rules of the other sports. What can I do with it? I am making a profit from it by playing directly the bets myself, but I would like to sell it (what could it be its value, 50.000$ more?), or findining somebody that has interest in it. It is 13000 lines of c

Comment: If you claim it is a foolproof method of winning it may be rejected in the same way a purported perpetual motion machine is -  not useful since it is theoretically impossible,

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky. To get a patent, one must disclose the invention. Something like a betting algorithm, even if it is patentable (and it may not be), would be very hard to detect infringement of. In other words, your patent would teach the world how your algorithm works and then anyone could implement it on their own. It would be very hard to prove a particular person is using the algorithm on their own since any particular person's betting history isn't common knowledge.

Probably better would be to keep the algorithm as a trade secret. You could then sell the compiled software or provide a website (software as a service) which might be easier to protect. In any case, those details are off topic for this site.